# Resource Missing Problem while gradle clean build

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

One of my projects build started failing due to Resource Missing Errors.
I tried organizing the build.gradle file. But that too didn't work out.

```
Resource missing. [HTTP HEAD: http://download.osgeo.org/webdav/geotools/io/swagger/swagger-project/1.5.13/swagger-project-1.5.13.pom]
Resource missing. [HTTP HEAD: http://download.osgeo.org/webdav/geotools/com/fasterxml/oss-parent/24/oss-parent-24.pom]
Resource missing. [HTTP HEAD: http://download.osgeo.org/webdav/geotools/org/mapstruct/mapstruct-parent/1.1.0.Final/mapstruct-parent-1.1.0.Final.pom]
Resource missing. [HTTP HEAD: http://download.osgeo.org/webdav/geotools/org/springframework/plugin/spring-plugin/1.2.0.RELEASE/spring-plugin-1.2.0.RELEASE.pom]
Resource missing. [HTTP HEAD: http://download.osgeo.org/webdav/geotools/io/swagger/swagger-project/1.5.13/swagger-project-1.5.13.jar]
Resource missing. [HTTP HEAD: http://download.osgeo.org/webdav/geotools/com/fasterxml/oss-parent/24/oss-parent-24.jar]
Resource missing. [HTTP HEAD: http://download.osgeo.org/webdav/geotools/org/mapstruct/mapstruct-parent/1.1.0.Final/mapstruct-parent-1.1.0.Final.jar]
Resource missing. [HTTP HEAD: http://download.osgeo.org/webdav/geotools/io/swagger/swagger-project/1.5.13/swagger-project-1.5.13.pom]
```

Expected Result is that every dependencies should be downloaded without any problems.
Actual Result is most of the dependencies are throwing Resource Missing error.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what "osgeo.org" is supposed to provide, but the artifacts you need clearly aren't in it.

At least the ones you have posted are found in both jcenter and maven central. So try using one of those instead. For instance, declare the following in your Gradle build file:

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}
```